# How to alter property of json object using another endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, express

I am trying to change the src of a picture depending on the option the user selects, i currently have a database tables of pictures of values that get selected depending on the choices, i have it where when the user selects one color the front end recieves the image source like so:

[image]

but when i go to input that url into the shirt.image property by doing:

```
    const shirtColorSource = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/products/${shirt.product_id}/${userColor}`);
    const shirtColor = await shirtColorSource.json();
    shirt.image = shirtColor;
    console.log(shirtColor);
```

it ends up looking like this:

[image]

which causes it not to render on my webpage so what exactly am i doing wrong and i know that the way it is storing it into shirt.image must not be the proper way of going about it.

Comment: Image goes from a string to an array and I assume you try to render shirt state so you should not mutate state, [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) is some information on how you can create a new changed state without mutating it.

Comment: @HMR Is there any way to just keep it a string and just inputed it directly?

Comment: You could try `shirtColor[0]`

Comment: How can i remove the "image" in image: http://localhost:5000/asdasd ?

Comment: @HMR Nevermind i figured it out thank you!

Comment: please marked it as answered question, glad you solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shirt.image = shirtColor[0].image solved the problem for me